# Отключение локализации библиотеки в Android приложении

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Всем привет.
Такой вопрос, как отключить локализацию текстов в UI подключаемой библиотеки? 
Использую Zendesk Support SDK for Android и пытаюсь сделать так что бы во всех его окнах всегда отображался только английский, так как все приложение на английском и поддерживать локализацию лишь в одной его части будет "некрасиво".
Сам я пока додумался только до созданий файлов ресурсов для других локалей с английским текстом, но мне это конечно не нравится.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет! Попробуй добавить в градл файл приложения вот эту строчку:
**resConfigs "en"**

Это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        ......
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.